# Terraform AWS SSM Parameter with multiple values

Tags: terraform, aws-ssm

I need to store multiple values related to the same environment in the SSM parameter store. What would be the best practice? Storing the values with the individual parameter? or storing everything in a single parameter?

When am storing it individually, it's pretty straight forward to get the value using the following terraform code.

SSM parameter `foo`

```
bar
```

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_parameters" {
  for_each = var.ssm_parameters
  name     = each.key
}

output "ssm_parameters" {
  value = tolist([
    for ssm_parameter in data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_parameters : ssm_parameter.value
  ])
}
```

Output:

```
➜  aws_ssm git:(add/ssm_resources) ✗ terraform apply -var-file="test.tfvars"
data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_parameters["foo"]: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

ssm_parameters = [
  "bar",
]
```

When am storing all values in a single parameter. Is there a way to get the values based on the particular key? For example, if I store the values something like below, is there a way to get only `server2` value? or `server1` `eth1` value?

SSM parameter `foo`:

```
[
  {
    server1_eth0 = “server_ip1"
    server1_eth1 = “server_ip2"
    server2 = “server2_ip"
    server3 = “server3_ip"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your secret is json, so you parse it in TF as such. Not sure what is the issue?

Comment: Are you asking how to access key value pairs?

Comment: Yes.. for example, how to get the value only for server 2 using terraform?

Comment: how to get the value of eth1 in server 1 using terraform..

Answer (score 1):

The following method helped me to solve this. Thanks, @Marcin, @Matt Schuchard

Paramter value:

```
"server_ips":
{ 
 "server1":"10.1.21.1",
 "server2":"10.1.22.1", 
 "server3":"10.1.23.1"
}
}
```

And the code is

```
output "ssm_parameters" {
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_parameters.value)["server_ips"].server3
}
```

Output is

```
Outputs:

ssm_parameters = 10.1.23.1
```